# A single word meaning 'gladly explain'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to eliminate the adverb in "as X will explain gladly". Which word would be suitable here?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend removing the ornamentation and going with *explain*. Strongly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Why 'strongly'?

Comment: 'with enthusiasm' should do the trick

Comment: One, because it comes across as unctuous. Two, because in "as X will..", you're speaking for someone else, which makes the first problem doubly worse, as while you're acting like a servant to whomever you're addressing, you're also acting as if X is *your* servant and will do whatever you instruct him to do, and gladly. And finally, that venerated advice editors and style guides have been touting for a century: [*omit needless words*](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk5.html). But mostly the servile attitude it conveys.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Not only does that not answer the OP's question -- it actually *adds* a word, instead of removing one -- it makes the problems I'm pointing out with using *gladly* in the first place even worse. No.

Comment: @DanBron; well 'enthusiastically' then  - which is way more silly bulls

Comment: @DanBron for all you know X told me he gladly explains stuff to my readers, it can't be that bad surely? In any case, it circumvents the original question rather than answers it.

Comment: @JMoons Yes, "circumventing" -- that is, pointing out a flaw in the premises -- was the precise point of my comment. It doesn't matter if X said he would gladly do Y, your audience doesn't know that, and all they hear is you speaking on behalf of another in a way that belittles him. And yourself. Hence the "circumvention" (and hence being a comment, instead of an answer). Having said all that, English doesn't have neat one-word packages for every possible concept, and I strongly doubt you'll find one for "gladly explain", but you're welcome to wait.

Comment: '... as X will be pleased to explain' sounds more idiomatic, without the 'it's what X lives for' connotation. Is there a reason why you want a verb meaning 'be pleased to explain'? There comes a point where it makes far more sense to use modification.

Comment: I accept that it might be better to leave the word out, but I'm surprised at the strong opposition :-) It seems to be quite the horrible question to ask. I'm using it as an introduction to a video in which the presenter gives the impression of being extremely happy to talk about his subject. I wasn't aware that formulating it like this would imply such strong connotations

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why does that variation make so much difference? It seems to say the exact same thing?

Comment: @DanBron I thought you were being sarcastic because you used the adverb 'strongly'. It's not funny anymore.

Comment: @JMoons It's not a horrible question to ask, though the answer to "is there one word to express ..." is likely "no". And if your presenter gives the impression of being very happy to explain, then your audience will see that, directly. There's no need to say it. Just as you wouldn't introduce Shaq as "and now may I present a very tall man, Shaq.". He's tall as anything. People will see it without being told. This goes to that other venerable writers' adage: *show, don't tell* (and I differ from Edwin's comment: I think the rephrasing makes no difference, and where I'm from it's not idiomatic).

Comment: @Mitch I wasn't being sarcastic, and I am not trying to be funny.

Comment: [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gladly) lists the senses of 'glad': << glad 1  
adj. 
1. a. Experiencing or exhibiting joy and pleasure. /
b. Appreciative: was glad to be home. //
2. Providing joy and pleasure: a glad occasion. //
3. Very willing; pleased: glad to help. >> While '... as X will gladly explain' is certainly not wrong, using the less common sense (though the adverb isn't available for sense (2)) certainly connotes the more common sense. If you check Google hits for "will be pleased to explain" and "will gladly explain", the first would seem far more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in a presentation a native speaker will politely indicate that someone will be glad to explain by saying something like *we welcome your questions*.  To be closer to the format in your original question, you could modify this phrase to *X will welcome questions* or whatever precisely fits your intended meaning.

Another common choice is *appreciate* as in *we appreciate your questions*.

The native style often translates something that means *happy* into something that means *anticipates* and will generally use the word *questions* instead of *explain* (but creating the same meaning) which results in a sort of softer style that you seem to be searching for and which is very common in business.  So one can also hear *X looks forward to your questions* or *X is eager to answer your questions* or something along those lines.